# Error while passing struct in the place of interface{}

Tags: go

So, I have a function like this

```
func ProcessRequest(requestBody *SignInRequest, response func(SignInResponse) *src.Response, error func(ControllerError) *src.Response) *src.Response {
    return error(ControllerError{Code: http.StatusNotImplemented})
}
```

And I'm trying to call this

```
ProcessRequest(payload, myFunction, handler.OnControllerError)


func myFunction(i interface{}) *src.Response {

}
```

This is showing me an error

> Cannot use 'myFunction' (type func(i interface{}) *src.Response) as the type func(SignInResponse) *src.Response

But if I try the same thing with

```
type TestStruct struct {
    
}

func myFunction2(i interface{}) *src.Response {

}

myFunction2(TestStruct{})
```

Then it is not showing any error.

I want it to take `interface{}` as an argument because I want `myFucntion` to be general which can take any `struct`.

Comment: myFunction may be general in what it accepts, but the response callback in ProcessRequest  is not.  This callback must have SignInResponse as its argument. Its not guruateed by providing a function with an empty interface as argument.

Comment: @TheFool can I use generics for the same?

Comment: The types `SignInResponse` and `interface{}` are not identical, and therefore the types `func (SignInResponse) *src.Response` and `func (interface{}) *src.Response` are also not identical.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah I got that but why it's working for the second case. also `SignInResponse` is definitely an `interface` no?

Comment: `SignInResponse` may or may not be an interface, regardless, it is not identical to `interface{}`. The second case works because `TestStruct{}` implements `interface{}`. The difference is the following: In the first case you are passing an argument to a function whose parameter is a **concrete** type and therefore the argument's type MUST be identical to the parameter's type. In the second case you are passing an argument to a function whose parameter is an interface type (an abstract, not-concrete, type) and therefore it is enough if the argument's type only satisfies the parameter's type.

Comment: Yeah @mkopriva make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two things.

When you have a function with the signaure `func (interface{}) *src.Response`, you indeed can *call* it while passing it a value of any type, but that is not what happens.

What happens is that you have another function, `ProcessRequest`, and one of the types of its arguments is a function with the type `func (SignInResponse) *src.Response`.
The error happens when you try to pass a value of type `func (interface{}) *src.Response` to a function which accepts an argument of type `func (SignInResponse) *src.Response` because the types of these arguments are obviously not compatible.

*Update.*
To understand why the types of the arguments are not compatible, consider that `SignInResponse` and `interface{}` have different storage representation in memory; basically that's the same reason why `[]T` and `[]interface{}` are not compatible even when you can do `t := T{}; var i interface{} = t`. This one is [explained in the FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

As to the problem at hand, supposedly the easiest approach is to use an anonymous function to "adapt" the value `SignInResponse` to `interface{}`: pass to `ProcessResponse` something like

```golang
func (r SignInResponse) *src.Response {
    return myFunction2(r)
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see what is happening. Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me what should I do if I want the same thing? Can I use generics?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun generics in Go 1.18 and up will help in your specific case **only if** `SignInResponse` method set is the same as that of `interface{}`, i.e. empty. https://go.dev/play/p/-v07csBhEuq?v=gotip. And you could of course use `any` like so: https://go.dev/play/p/F5F2W70nOyF?v=gotip but then you lose the potentially relevant type info.

Comment: It's very hard to judge without seeing more context. Usually problems like yours signalize some architecture problem. Still, if I were to give an immediate response, I'd say "use an adapter": you can pass to your `Processrequest` a simple anonymous function which would look like `func (r SignInResponse) *src.Response { return myFunction2(r) }`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun with Go 1.18 you can declare `ProcessRequest` as `ProcessRequest[T any](requestBody *SignInRequest, response func(T) *src.Response, error func(ControllerError) *src.Response) *src.Response`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun, updated with the more info (including the adaptor function approach).

Comment: @blackgreen tired but getting the same kinda error.

Comment: *"the same kinda error"* -- And you've got Go 1.18 installed @OhhhThatVarun yes? You understand that the current version, version 1.17, does not have generics support, yes?

Comment: @mkopriva yes I'm aware of that and I have installed the latest version.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun then you should either open a new question or update your old question with the Go1.18 version of your code and make sure to include the exact error message that that code produces.